# ASP SQL How to check if username already exists in database table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am currently working with SQL database and my assignment is to make a registration form. I have got the registration form to work but I need to check if username have already been taken. In my code Username is in the form of Emails. The code I have works, but as it is, multiple usernames are allowed.
HEre is my code:

```
protected void registerUser(Object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("you have connected to your .cs page add records");
        get_connection();
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO subscribers (FirstName, LastName, Email, Password)" +
                " VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @Password)", connection);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //connection.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            lblInfo.Text = "Error reading the database. ";
            lblInfo.Text += err.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            lblInfo.Text += "<br /><b>Record has been added</b>";
            //lblInfo.Text = "<b>Server Version:</b> " + connection.ServerVersion;
            lblInfo.Text += "<br /><b>Connection Is:</b> " + connection.State.ToString();
        }
    }
```

To check if the username had already been taken, I was thinking about using an "If Then" statement within the "try" area but am unsure what coding I would need. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I understand you may be still be learning, but storing passwords in plaintext in the database is a big security violation. Passwords should be one way hashed and salted, never stored in plaintext. If you're still in school, then it will be best if you learn how to do that now before going out into the real and not knowing how with real data.

Comment: Off topic - but think carefully about your current exception handling. Assume an error is thrown. Your code catches it and some text is changed. What happens then? Hint - something that shouldn't. In addition, your catch error message is not correct. Any error caught is not related to "reading the database" from a user's perspective. Lastly, the fact that "multiple usernames are allowed" is a schema problem. Correct that first, then test your error handling and correct that. Then add your checking logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this:

```
 string cmdText = @"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM subscribers where Email = @Email) 
     INSERT INTO subscribers (FirstName, LastName, Email, Password)
                      VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @Password)"

 command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
 ......
```

Comment: Thank you the code does work, but what would be a way to let users know that the username would be taken?

Comment: It is simple. The ExecuteNonQuery returns a number that is the number of rows inserted. If this value (an integer) is 1 then your insert executed and the EMail were available, if the result of ExecuteNonQuery is -1 then nothing has been done and you know that the email already exists. Take this value and use some logic (if ) to display the appropriate message

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
 string sqlQuery =   "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM subscribers where Email = @Email) 
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO subscribers (FirstName, LastName, Email, Password) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @Password)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
    ELSE SELECT 0"

using (command = new SqlCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

    connection.Open();
    var res = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();
}
```

if a result is 0 then already exists otherwise new record inserted.